# C implementation of skew heap

Tags: c, heap, skew

I'm trying to implement a skew heap in C, but my code doesn't compile. I'm not that experienced in C and never created any type of heap in C. That is why I don't know how to fix it, I'm hoping someone can point me the right direction. I have been reading articles about the skew heap and this is what I got so far using the algorithms I have found online. Thanks in Advance.

```
typedef struct node
{
int value;
struct node * root;
struct node * leftchild;
struct node * rightchild;
} Node;

struct skewHeap
{
    struct node * root;
};

void skewHeapInit (struct skewHeap * sk)
{
    sk->root = 0;
}

void skewHeapAdd (struct skewHeap *sk)
{
    struct node *n = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    assert(n != 0);
    n->value = 0;
    n->leftchild = 0;
    n->rightchild = 0;
    line 185. s->root = skewHeapMerge(s->root, n);
}

void skewHeapRemoveFirst (struct skewHeap *sk)
{
    struct node * n = sk->root;
    free(n);
    sk->root = skewHeapMerge(n->leftchild, n->rightchild);
}

line 196. struct node * skewHeapMerge(struct node *left, struct node *right)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (left == NULL) 
        return *right;

    if (right == NULL) 
        return *left;

    if (left->value < right-> value)
    {
        temp = left->leftchild;
        left->leftchild = skewHeapMerge(left->rightchild, right);
        left->rightchild = temp;
        return left;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = right->rightchild;
        right->rightchild = skewHeapMerge(right->leftchild, left);
        right->leftchild = temp;
        return right;
    }
}
```

These are the compilations errors I'm getting at the moment:

```
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapAdd’:
program.c:185: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘skewHeapMerge’
program.c:185: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapRemoveFirst’:
program.c:191: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
program.c: At top level:
program.c:196: error: conflicting types for ‘skewHeapMerge’
program.c:185: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘skewHeapMerge’ was here
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapMerge’:
program.c:202: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct node’ but ‘struct   node *’ was expected
program.c:205: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct node’ but ‘struct node *’ was expected
```

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: It looks like you have written an entire program, then compiled and gotten overwhelmed.  Try to get in the habit of writing a little bit of code, and compiling it.  Combine that with reading what the compiler error messages say.  You should always start with the *first* error message, as it may cause other error messages that are confusing.

Comment: its a bit of a mess!  you are going to bleed memory in your merge, your temp doesn't need to be assigned memory, you are just using it to point to existing memory. You haven't shown the definition of "node"

Comment: Unrelated to compiler errors, but your function `skewHeapRemoveFirst` frees `n` at the wrong time.  You cannot use `n` after it has been freed.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid comments guys. This is the Node definition I have:

   'typedef struct node
    {
 int value;
 struct node * leftchild;
 struct node * rightchild;
    } Node;'

Comment: I have edited my question to include the node definition and compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the compiler errors,

```
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapAdd’:
program.c:185: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘skewHeapMerge’
program.c:185: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

tells you that no prototype of `skewHeapMerge` is in scope where `skewHeapAdd` is defined, hence (the compiler apparently operates in C89 mode, but thankfully warns about it), the compiler supposes an implicit declaration with return type `int` for `skewHeapMerge`.

Add a header file with prototypes for all your functions, and `#include` that in all `*.c` files where these functions are used or defined, so that the compiler knows the types of the functions.

```
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapRemoveFirst’:
program.c:191: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

that should be the line

```
sk->root = skewHeapMerge(n->leftchild, n->rightchild);
```

where `sk->root` is a `struct node*`, but due to the implicit declaration of `skewHeapMerge`, that is assumed to return an `int`.

```
program.c: At top level:
program.c:196: error: conflicting types for ‘skewHeapMerge’
program.c:185: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘skewHeapMerge’ was here
```

here the compiler finds that the definition of `skewHeapMerge` gives a type conflicting with the one from the implicit declaration.

```
program.c: In function ‘skewHeapMerge’:
program.c:202: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct node’ but ‘struct   node *’ was expected
program.c:205: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct node’ but ‘struct node *’ was expected
```

That is for the lines

```
if (left == NULL) 
    return *right;

if (right == NULL) 
    return *left;
```

where you ought to return `right` resp. `left` instead of `*right` resp. `*left` (I overlooked that at first).

---

You have a mistake in `skewHeapRemoveFirst`

```
void skewHeapRemoveFirst (struct skewHeap *sk)
{
    struct node * n = sk->root;
    free(n);
    sk->root = skewHeapMerge(n->leftchild, n->rightchild);
}
```

where you use `n` after you `free`d it. You have to exchange the last two lines in that function.

And in `skewHeapMerge`

```
struct node * skewHeapMerge(struct node *left, struct node *right)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (left == NULL)
        return *right;

    if (right == NULL)
        return *left;
```

you are leaking memory. Remove the allocation, since if `temp` is used at all, you assign either `left->leftchild` or `right->rightchild` to it.

Comment: Updated with a discussion of the compiler messages.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation, got it to compile without errors.